# Install foo2zjs Driver on MacOS X?

Tags: printing, driver, cups

[Reposted from https://macosx.com/threads/foo2zjs-driver-for-hp-laserjet-1018.327123/ and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1345298/install-foo2zjs-driver-on-macos-x.]

I have a friend who uses MacOS X 11.2 Big Sur and she would like to print to an HP LaserJet 1018.

I use Ubuntu, and I just plugged in the printer to my spiffy System76 laptop's USB port, waited a few seconds, got a pop-up message the printer was installed, and printed my stuff.

My System76 laptop uses the foo2zjs driver in CUPS for the printer, evidently, but I can't figure out how to download/compile/install that driver on her OS X laptop. The website http://foo2zjs.rkkda.com/ appears to be permanently down, so I can't even download it from there. I installed HomeBrew and CakeBrew on her machine; a solution using CakeBrew would be just stellar.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/LaserJet-Printing/Is-it-possible-to-run-an-HP-Laserjet-1018-on-MacOS-Catalina/td-p/7468304 or https://github.com/koenkooi/foo2zjs/blob/master/INSTALL.osx

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks so much for the reply! I tried the HP directions, and HP Printer Drivers v5.1 for OS X doesn't work with OS 11.2, only 10 and below. I tried the GitHub, and Step 5) is "5) Now install foo2zjs.  Browse to: ttp://foo2zjs.rkkda.com/", which, that website seems permanently down. Thanks so much again for replying

Answer (score 2):

You can access the foo2zjs website on the WayBack Machine:

https://web.archive.org/web/20210129024712/http://foo2zjs.rkkda.com/

You could also try using [Pacifist](https://www.charlessoft.com) (a third-party app that lets you browse through .pkg files and install the contents, regardless of any compatibility checks. I would be surprised if the drivers for your printer in the HP v5.1 set didn't still work.

Answer (score -1):

The amount of hoop jumping required to add the macOS Big Sur CUPS driver is not worth the effort. The combination of SIP (System Integrity Protection) and the signed bootable APFS snapshot macOS System volume makes it very difficult to add the CUPS driver even if you could locate the driver source and compile it yourself since the original foo2zjs driver doesn't appear to be accessible any longer.

The printer is 12+ years old. Apple had issues with some other non-CUPS HP printer drivers whose drivers weren't notarized and the solution was to use AirPrint instead of drivers from HP. Most all new printers support Bonjour/ZeroConf/AirPrint.

Try going to the Mac App Store and searching for HP Smart for Desktop and installing that. With luck, it will detect the USB printer and offer a compatible driver for Big Sur. If that doesn't work then you may need to pursue a print server solution.

There are expensive commercial products such as the LANTRONIX xPrintServer which sells new for $363.40. But if you search eBay you can find an older used one under $60 USD. You plug the USB cable into the xPrintServer box as well as Ethernet & power and it makes the printer available over AirPrint to multiple devices including mobile devices. Big Sur will certainly be able to automatically add any AirPrint printer. Or you could build a DIY tiny computer such as a RaspberryPi, etc. running Linux with CUPS and AirPrint capabilities. That might be a fun little project and you could run other things on the RaspberryPi such as Pi-Hole or home automation projects. That option would cost more in materials and time spent.

The other alternative to consider buying a new printer. New models all support AirPrint and newer small desktop LaserJets are cheaper than the original cost of the HP LaserJet 1018 printer. You'll get better speed and more importantly, support for years to come.

Comment: So, first off, I super-appreciate you replying! Next, I tried the HP Smart for Desktop on her PC, and it didn't recognize the printer (that there was any printer connected) via USB. That was probably the best bet. I will see if I can get a LANTRONIX on the cheap, otherwise, I'll have to punt on this one https://youtu.be/HnemVxvTNS0?t=54 Thanks again, I really appreciate ti

Comment: CUPS is not covered by SIP, so I'm not sure what hoops need jumping. You can add backends, filters, PPDs, etc to CUPS just with admin privileges.